# Imagenes en React

Tags: reactjs, imagen

Tengo un problema al mostrar imagenes en un componente.
En la parte de **props.item.logo**. Como ven todo ser recorre bien, sin embargo la imagen no carga y se queda nada mas con el alt. No se que pueda ser. La informacion viene de un componente padre que a su vez esta viene de un JSON.

````
const JobPositionitem = (props) => {
  return (
    <div className="jobPositionItem">
      <img src={props.item.logo} alt="logoCompany" />
      <div className="jobPositionItem-section-2">
        <div className="jobPositionItem-section-2-bubbles">
          <p>{props.item.company}</p>
          {props.item.new ? <p>NEW!</p> : null}
          {props.item.featured ? <p>FEATURED</p> : null}
        </div>
        <h4>{props.item.position}</h4>
        <ul>
          <li>{props.item.postedAt}</li>
          <li>{props.item.contract}</li>
          <li>{props.item.location}</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div className="jobPositionItem-section-3">
        <ul>
          <li>{props.item.role}</li>
          <li>{props.item.level}</li>
          {props.item.languages.map((item) => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};``` 


**COMPONENTE PADRE**

const JobPositionContainer = (props) => (
  <div className="jobPositionContainer">
    {
      props.items.map( item => <JobPositionItem key={item.id} item={item} />)
    }
  </div>
);
````

Comment: ¿y has revisado que efectivamente venga una url en `props.item.logo`? ¿o que `props.items` en el componente padre traiga algo?

Comment: Si inspeccionas tu página en el explorador. ¿Cómo aparece `<img src={props.item.logo} alt="logoCompany" />` renderizado?

Comment: @FranAcuna `<img src="./images/photosnap.svg" alt="logoCompany">`
Asi queda

Comment: @AlterLagos Sii, cuando inspecciono, o hago console.log el elemento viene la url que viene del JSON, la cambie de ahi tambien pero no funciono

Comment: @BetoMartinez Usar `<img src="images/photosnap.svg" alt="logoCompany">` hace alguna diferencia? Mira [esto](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp)

Comment: @FranAcuna No :(. La ruta viene desde el JSON, creo que puede ser eso.
Este es un ejemplo de un objeto del JSON
`
{
    "id": 1,
    "company": "Photosnap",
    "logo": "./images/photosnap.svg",
    "new": true,
    "featured": true,
    "position": "Senior Frontend Developer",
    "role": "Frontend",
    "level": "Senior",
    "postedAt": "1d ago",
    "contract": "Full Time",
    "location": "USA Only",
    "languages": ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"],
    "tools": []
  }`

Comment: @FranAcuna Te dejo el repositorio por si tienes tiempo de echarle un ojo. Gracias
[Repositorio](https://github.com/Betoml5/FrontEndMentor-7)

Comment: ¿y has verificado que efectivamente la imagen existe en la ruta que te carga? porque por lo que mencionas en comentarios, claramente está cargando la info del json sin problemas.

Comment: @AlterLagos Si, porque si importo una imagen y la pongo estatica, si carga, el problema es al iterar